# How to add C daemon to android project and run it?

Tags: android, c, daemon

I have a daemon written in C language. I also have an android application that uses this daemon via socket. Daemon run with system. Is it possible to add compilled C daemon to android application and run it from application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is possible, but just in case your device is rooted.You should include the daemon as part of your application, see [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) if you don't know how to do it, and somwhere in your application code call it like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su root " + "path to daemon");
```

where 'su' is super user utility, which forks your application and executes daemon in sepparate proccess with elevated permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this, but you can start here [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)